# Page is stop working while getting large number of data

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote simple PHP code for getting data from MySQL server and run a while loop for display data while I'm displaying the data page shows This page isn’t working. HTTP 500 error,

here my code

```
<?php
include('dbConnection.php');
?>

<select  class="form-control m-select2" style="width:100%;" data-placeholder="Select City Name">
    <option value="">Select City</option>
    <?php
    $cityQuery = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from `city` where `delete` = 0");
    $i = 1;
    while ($cityRow = mysqli_fetch_array($cityQuery)) {
    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $cityRow['cityId']; ?>"><?php echo $cityRow['cityName'];  ?> </option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

after I remove the while loop my page is working fine. Or even if add just a limit of less than 200 then my page is working fine. and I have 5741 rows and 3 columns in my city table. and I also try to add specific col instead of * in MySQL query but the result is the same as my page Is not working.

**Note: I'm getting this error in my live server, in my localhost it's working fine.**

Comment: i think http 500 error is syntax error enable error and then try

Comment: @shubham I also try this and I upload this code to another server and it's working fine.

Comment: ` ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` use this code for error reporting

Comment: @shubham ok I put this code in my file but no error shows. but it's showing a blank white page now.

Comment: You have to rethink the UI. A select with 5000 options is not usable.

Comment: I think it's better to show city according to  selected state.   first select state and then according to state value show city.

Comment: Changing the memory_limit and timeout limit in php.ini could help. The PHP error log should have more details on the error. Posting that would help.

Comment: Is your `delete` field indexed? This may change performance of the query itself. You could also try to do a `mysqli_fetch_all()` and then iterate on the results. Some people say it is a bit more efficient than calling `mysqli_fetch_array()` several times.

Comment: @Sharky I partly agree, but this is a select2, so a searchable select. So it could be usable.

Comment: Okay, finally it's working thank you @qwertynik, and ALL of you who give me your valuable suggestions. thank you, thank you so much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the memory_limit and timeout limit in php.ini could help